# How to fix error with flutter_google_places_autocomplete.dart?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-places-autocomplete

I make an application with Google maps in which you can find a place and build a path to it on the map. I want to show places and addresses below it according to what the user types.After showing the results, I need to get its latitude and longitude to mark on the map.

I tried to use a `flutter_google_places: 0.2.3` but functions(GoogleMapsPlaces, Prediction) were not defined. Next i used `flutter_google_places_autocomplete: 0.1.3` and everything was fine. Unfortunately when i tride to run the project I got an error:

> Compiler message:
>   file:///C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_google_places_autocomplete-0.1.3/lib/src/flutter_google_places_autocomplete.dart:337:35:
>   Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found. Try
>   removing the extra positional arguments.
>       _places = new GoogleMapsPlaces(widget.apiKey);
>                                     ^ file:///C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_webservice-0.0.14/lib/src/places.dart:22:3:
>   Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
>   GoogleMapsPlaces({   ^ Compiler failed on
>   C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\advertise_me\lib\main.dart
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\Users\admin\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>     line: 647
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileflutterBuildDebugandroid-arm64'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 9s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

My pubspes.yaml:

> dependencies:   flutter:
>       sdk: flutter
>
> cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2   url_launcher: ^4.2.0+1
>   google_maps_flutter:   bottom_sheet_stateful: ^0.1.1
>   flutter_google_places_autocomplete: 0.1.3   geocoder: 0.1.2
>   google_maps_webservice: 0.0.14

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:advertise_me/login_screen.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/geocoding.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places_autocomplete/flutter_google_places_autocomplete.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const kGoogleApiKey = "My key";


GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: demo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  demoState createState() => new demoState();
}

class demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Prediction p = await showGooglePlacesAutocomplete(
                    context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                displayPrediction(p);
              },
              child: Text('Find address'),

            )
        )
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
    }
  }
}
```

How do i fix this error?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flutter_google_places_autocomplete` is deprecated and you should use `flutter_google_places` instead. See documentation : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places_autocomplete

And once you use `flutter_google_places`, use

`Prediction p = await PlacesAutoComplete.show()` instead of `showGooglePlacesAutoComplete()`

======= updated answer =====

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:advertise_me/login_screen.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const kGoogleApiKey = "My key";


GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: demo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  demoState createState() => new demoState();
}

class demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                    context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                displayPrediction(p);
              },
              child: Text('Find address'),

            )
        )
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am very inattentive. However, after I import flutter_google_places: 0.2.3 there were errors(Undefined class 'GoogleMapsPlaces'.The function 'GoogleMapsPlaces' isn't defined. Undefined class 'Prediction'. Undefined class 'Prediction'. Undefined class 'PlacesDetailsResponse'.). Can you help me with there problems or Should I ask this in another question?

Comment: That's because your code was missing correct imports. In order to use `GoogleMapsPlaces`, `Prediction` and `PlacesDetailsResponse`, you need to import `package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart`.  I updated my answer with working code. That should resolve issues you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that i had to import: google_maps_webservice/places. Could you tell me why Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'geometry' was called on null. I think this is Prediction p = null, but why is this happening? I chose the place or I doing something wrong? If it is true, how can i get the location of place the user clicked on?

Comment: Could be due to the google api configured to your project. Check if that's enabled and working as expected with respect to api key.  See this issue posted against the plugin : https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/issues/51

Comment: Also, I think your original issue has been resolved for which you posted your question at first. If so, you may accept my answer for others to know as well :-)

Comment: @Darshan Could you tell me which service on google cloud must to be enabled for GoogleMapsPlace service api get the rest API responses?

Answer (score 1):

Use complete list of function parameters like:

```
Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show( offset: 0, radius: 1000, types: [], strictbounds: false,
region: "ar", context: context, apiKey: googleAPIKey, mode: Mode.overlay, language: "es", components: [Component(Component.country, "ar")] );
```

Answer (score 0):

use import `'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';` along with, import `'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';`