# Flutter can't running, after use google_maps_autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-autocomplete

I copied this code from flutter_google_places_autocomplete, but my app can't starting more.

How can i solve this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places_autocomplete/flutter_google_places_autocomplete.dart';
import 'package:flutter_prayer_times/place_search_banner_field.dart';


// Google Api Key
const googleMapsApiKey = "......";

// to get places detail (lat/lng)
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: googleMapsApiKey);
```

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Kotlin plugin should be enabled before 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Compiler message:
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_google_places_autocomplete-0.1.0/lib/src/flutter_google_places_autocomplete.dart:327:35: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    _places = new GoogleMapsPlaces(widget.apiKey);
                                  ^
file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_webservice-0.0.14/lib/src/places.dart:22:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  GoogleMapsPlaces({
  ^
Compiler failed on C:\Users\GaminKh\Desktop\MyProjects\prayertimes\flutter_prayer_times\lib\main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: flutter_google_places_autocomplete seems deprecated. can you try with flutter_google_places package.

Comment: Thank you @ArjavDave, the answer was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter_google_places_autocomplete` is deprecated and you should use `flutter_google_places`. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859043/how-to-fix-error-with-flutter-google-places-autocomplete-dart/56863205#56863205) for complete answer.

Comment: Thank you Too @DK15, I use now the flutter_google_places stead the flutter_google_palces_autocomplete.